# JobExplorer spring batch and table prefix

Tags: java, spring, batch-file

Is it really needed the table prefix of jobRepository tables to be changed for the jobExplorer bean?

This is what the documentation says about it:

> Earlier in this chapter, it was mentioned that the table prefix of the
>   JobRepository can be modified to allow for different versions or
>   schemas. Because the JobExplorer is working with the same tables, it
>   too needs the ability to set a prefix:

`class="org.spr...JobExplorerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:tablePrefix="BATCH_" />`

If the jobExplorer is only for reading purposes.. why should we have another set of jobRepository tables for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have one set of tables for both jobRepository and jobExplorer. Both beans will use the default table prefix BATCH_ if you don't change it explicitly (which you normally won't).
The documentation only states, that *IF* you change the table prefix when configuring the jobRepository *THEN* make sure, that you also change the table prefix of the jobExplorer to ensure, that both are using the same batch database tables.

Comment: Yhea I guess so too, however could you make me an example of a real case where changing the prefix is actually useful?

Comment: The only useful  real example I can imagine is, if you need to add the Spring Batch tables to an existing database schema where table_names with the same prefix already exists and used for a different context. But I have never seen such a scenario yet.

Comment: Rainer Montag - How we can do that ?